# Converted From VB.NET to C# - Not Returning Values Correctly

Tags: c#, vb.net, dllimport, interopservices

The original VB.net, which is working perfectly:

```
Declare Function HolderName Lib "myCard.dll" (ByVal buf As String) As Integer
Declare Function Photo Lib "myCard.dll" (ByRef photo As Byte) As Integer

...

buff = Space(200) : res = HolderName(buff)
ShowMsg("HolderName():" & IIf(res = 0, "OK:" & Trim(buff), "FAIL"))

photobuf = New Byte(4096) {}
res = Photo(photobuf(0))
ShowMsg("Photo():" & IIf(res = 0, "OK", "FAIL"))
If res = 0 Then
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(photobuf)
    picImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
End If
```

The converted code now in C# (using http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport("myCard.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int HolderName(String dBuff);

[DllImport("myCard.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int Photo(ref byte photo);

//...

buff = new String(' ', 200);
res = HolderName(buff);
// buff remains UNALTERED!
ShowMsg("HolderName():" + (res == 0 ? "OK:" + Strings.Trim(buff) : "FAIL"));

photobuf = new byte[4096];
res = Photo(ref photobuf[0]);
ShowMsg("Photo():" + (res == 0 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));

// photobuf successfully receives the data bytes from Photo function
if (res == 0)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photobuf);
    picImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The problem is `buff` remains unaltered even though the `HolderName` function actually returns some values (watched using USB Monitor).  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How is the variable `res` declared in the C#?

Comment: Can you post some input and expected output vs actual ouput?

Comment: Are you saying that the `HolderName` function is meant to alter the string parameter it's passed? And that this is working under VB? I'm not sure it should.

Comment: It seems the VB version should not work too, its passing ByVal

Comment: The VB version is working perfectly!

Comment: I agree after looking more into this from the other comments.  HolderName takes a standard parameter by value, not a reference and returns an int.  How do you expect a string to be returned?

Comment: [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) is talking about compact framework, but note: "the full .NET Framework does not support passing strings by value or by reference into unmanaged functions and allowing the unmanaged function to modify the contents of the buffer ... in the full .NET Framework, you can, instead, pass a System.Text.StringBuilder object"

Comment: Results from VB;
buff = "The HolderName"
picImage displays the picture of the HolderName

Results from C#;
buff = "                                                  " // space (200)
picImage displays the picture of the HolderName

Comment: Your converted array creation is incorrect - it should be: photobuf = new byte[4097]; (note that VB uses the upper bound when creating arrays, not the length).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I answered my own question. StringBuilder is the answer! Here's the codes...

```
        [DllImport("mykaddll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int HolderName([Out] StringBuilder dBuff);

        //....

        StringBuilder sbBuff = new StringBuilder(200);
        res = HolderName(sbBuff);
        buf = sbBuff.ToString().Trim();
        ShowMsg("HolderName():" + (res == 0 ? "OK:" + buf : "FAIL"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this code started life in VB6.  It *could* work in that language, but grave trouble today.  Both [DllImport] declarations are wrong.

You let the native HolderName() function modify the content of a string.  That's illegal, strings in .NET are immutable.  You *must* declare the argument as StringBuilder instead.  And set its Capacity high enough before you make the call.  Beware that it is a risky function, you can't tell it to avoid writing beyond the allocated capacity.

When it does it corrupts the GC heap, very nasty problem to debug.

The problem with Photo() is that its argument is *actually* byte[], no ref.  Tends to work by accident, a very common accident.  But the big, big problem is that the pinvoke marshaller doesn't know that the array needs to be pinned.  When the garbage collector runs while Photo() is running, it will jerk the floor mat and move the array elsewhere.  Photo() doesn't know and keeps using the old address.

When it does it corrupts the GC heap, very nasty problem to debug.

Otherwise no fantastic reason why it would work in VB.NET but not in C#.  I suspect a framework change as a better explanation.  But a necessary starting point certainly is to eliminate the bugs, these kind of corruption problems are very hard to reason through.

Comment: I just wish I had access to the .dll source code. This is a 3rd party .dll that came with the SDK kit that I bought. They provide examples for VB.net only, and I have to convert it to C#...

Comment: Changing the [DllImport] declarations doesn't require a change in the DLL.  Just assume that the equipment vendor hasn't had any decent programmer on staff for the past 15+ years and fix them.  Common problem btw.

Comment: Isn't there a [very] high chance for a buffer overflow as well in BOTH of those calls?  Or is that what you're referring to in regarding corrupting the GC Heap

Comment: Very well @ Hans Passant. Could you suggest a work around? Sample codes perhaps?

Comment: I already told you, use StringBuilder and byte[] instead.  Get cracking at it, nobody can predict success.  If you want to feel better about it then use a telephone.

Comment: @sambyte: If you're curious, see [What is the difference in a P/Invoke signature between “byref byte” and “byte”?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450200.aspx) for a discussion of why `ref byte` sometimes works.